# Error de Request.Cookies en c#

Tags: c#, .net, reportviewer

tengo un detalle con mi aplicación web, funciona bien, pero después de usarla varias veces sale el mensaje de error que muestro en la imagen y para solucionarlo por el momento lo que hago es borrar el cache de mi navegador, ¿cómo podría solucionarlo? ayudaaaa :( uso .NET FRAMEWORK 4

perdón por la calidad de la imagen pero es que así sale porque es de una máquina virtual
[image: ERROR]

Archivos:
[image: archivos]

Muestro el código que tiene el archivo Default.aspx la aplicación es un reporte de asistencia de empleados

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master" AutoEventWireup="true"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="Assistance_Report_Manager2._Default" %>

<%@ Register Assembly="Microsoft.ReportViewer.WebForms, Version=10.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"
    Namespace="Microsoft.Reporting.WebForms" TagPrefix="rsweb" %>
<%@ Register assembly="Telerik.Web.UI" namespace="Telerik.Web.UI" tagprefix="telerik" %>

<asp:Content ID="HeaderContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <p style="color:Navy;font-size:medium;font-weight:bold">Detalle de Asistencias</p>
    <p>
        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Departamento: "></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="cmbDepartment" runat="server" Height="44px" Width="257px" 
            DataSourceID="sourceDepartment" DataTextField="dept_name" 
            DataValueField="id">
        </asp:DropDownList>
        <asp:CheckBox ID="chkAll" runat="server" Text="Todos" AutoPostBack="True" 
            oncheckedchanged="chkAll_CheckedChanged" />
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sourceDepartment" runat="server" ConnectionString="<%$ConnectionStrings:BioTimeConnection%>" ProviderName="<%$ConnectionStrings:BioTimeConnection.providerName%>"
    SelectCommand="SELECT id, dept_name FROM biotime.personnel_department Where is_default = 0"></asp:SqlDataSource>
        <div>
            Fecha inicial:
            <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="pickerFirstDate" Runat="server" Culture="es-MX" 
                MinDate="2017-01-01" Width="228px">
                <calendar ID="Calendar1" runat="server" usecolumnheadersasselectors="False" userowheadersasselectors="False" 
                    viewselectortext="x">
                </calendar>
                <dateinput ID="Dateinput1" runat="server" dateformat="dd/MM/yyyy" displaydateformat="dd/MM/yyyy" labelwidth="">
                </dateinput>
                <datepopupbutton hoverimageurl="" imageurl="" />
            </telerik:RadDatePicker>
            Fecha final:
            <telerik:RadDatePicker ID="pickerSecondDate" Runat="server" Culture="es-MX" 
                MinDate="2017-01-01" Width="228px">
                <calendar ID="Calendar2" runat="server" usecolumnheadersasselectors="False" userowheadersasselectors="False" 
                    viewselectortext="x">
                </calendar>
                <dateinput ID="Dateinput2" runat="server" dateformat="dd/MM/yyyy" displaydateformat="dd/MM/yyyy" labelwidth="">
                </dateinput>
                <datepopupbutton hoverimageurl="" imageurl="" />
            </telerik:RadDatePicker>
        </div>
        <div>
            <br />
            <telerik:RadButton ID="btnGenerate" runat="server" onclick="btnGenerate_Click" 
                Text="Generar Reporte">
            </telerik:RadButton>
        </div>
    <asp:Label ID="lblNotes" runat="server" ForeColor="Red" Visible="False"></asp:Label>
    </p>
<p>
        </p>
    <rsweb:ReportViewer ID="ReportViewer1" runat="server" Width="903px" 
        Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" Height="765px" 
        InteractiveDeviceInfos="(Collection)" WaitMessageFont-Names="Verdana" 
        WaitMessageFont-Size="14pt">
    </rsweb:ReportViewer>    
    <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="AssistanceDataSource" runat="server" 
        SelectMethod="Select" TypeName="Assistance_Report_Manager2.App_Code.AssistanceLoader">
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="pickerFirstDate" Name="firstDate" 
                PropertyName="SelectedDate" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="pickerSecondDate" Name="secondDate" 
                PropertyName="SelectedDate" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="cmbDepartment" Name="departmentId" 
                PropertyName="SelectedValue" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="chkAll" Name="isForAllEmployees" 
                PropertyName="Checked" Type="Boolean" />
        </SelectParameters>
    </asp:ObjectDataSource>
    
    <p>
         <a href="http://www.reporte.com"  title="Biotime">    
         Regresar a sistema de tiempo y asistencia</a>.
         <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
         </asp:ScriptManager>
    </p>
    <p>
        &nbsp;</p>
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: porqué en la cookie hay un HTML?

Comment: Hola @L.Ronquillo la verdad es que entiendo muy poco de c# ¿sabes donde podría encontrar esa cookie? y ¿qué podría hacer para solucionarlo? :(

Comment: no tengo nada de información acerca del programa que estás haciendo, así que no sabría que decirte. ¿usas algún inicio de sesión?

Comment: en el proyecto si viene un archivo de login pero la verdad es que no lo usamos, la página que usamos es la Default.aspx este proyecto me lo pasaron solo para hacerle unas actualizaciones al sql según antes funcionaba bien, pero ahora después de usarlo varias veces sale eso. @L.Ronquillo

Comment: No sé si tenga algo que ver que la ruta que aparece en el navegador tenga %20 ya que el nombre de la carpeta contiene espacios :/

Comment: tenes que copiar el codigo de esa pagina, y no tiene sentido que tapes direcciones.

Comment: necesitamos más información para darnos idea de qué puede ser, puedes compartir código?

Comment: si, ya subí el código